# Regarding expected value of distance with respect to p

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

> Given a fixed point $a$ in $\{-1,1\}^{p}$. Let $X$ denote a uniformly randomly selected point $\{-1,1\}^{p}$. Let $D = d_{E}(a,X)^{2}$ denote the squared Euclidean distance. What is the expected value of D as a function of p?

I am able to get the probability of selecting a point in the hypercube which is $2^{-p}$ and the squared distance between the points in the hypercube is at the most 4. But am stuck on the step as to how to calculate the expected value of $D$.

Could you please share some hints on the same?

Comment: Note that $D$ is just the sum of the coordinate-wise distances (as it is squared).  Assume $p=1$; can you calculate the expected value of $D$?  What does this imply about the expected value of $D$ for any $p > 1$?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I am able to figure it now for p=1 expected value of D is 2